# Add label to pdf document itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to join multiple pdf files into one single file. (Below i write the function that i'm using).

Now i have a new requirement, I need to set a label with some text inside the first page. The label should be placed on top of any existing content.

I would like to write a function that receives a page (of type PdfImportedPage)  and a string as parameters, modifies the page adding a label and returns the modified page.

Thanks for helping

This is the function that i use:

```
public byte[] Join(params byte[][] files)
{
     byte[] mergedPdf = null;
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
           using (Document document = new Document())
           {
                using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms))
                {
                    document.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count(); ++i)
                    {
                        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(files[i]))//stampedDoc))
                        {
                            // loop over the pages in that document
                            int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                            for (int page = 0; page < n; )
                            {
                                var addPage = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page);
                                copy.AddPage(addPage);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                mergedPdf = ms.ToArray();
            }
            return mergedPdf;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I wrote this function without success.

```
private void AddText(PdfCopy copy, string text)
{
     var pageStamp = copy.CreatePageStamp(addPage);
     var over = pageStamp.GetOverContent();
     overContent.SaveState();
     overContent.BeginText();
     BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
     overContent.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10 );
     overContent.SetTextMatrix( 100, 100);
     overContent.ShowText(text);
     overContent.EndText();
     overContent.RestoreState();

 }
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Clean up the text (there are way to many typos such as cronstructing), but also make sure that a reader understands what you're actually asking. What is this *label, image or whatever setting somo text* you're babbling about? I don't see it in your code anywhere, nor can I imagine what it would look like. Take one step back and explain what you are trying to achieve in plain words.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie i wrote it again, trying to be more concise, and correcting my typos. Thanks for your comment,

Comment: @Alberto, when you say `Label`, are you trying to add a watermark on your pages?

Comment: @Nkosi no i'm not but it's a possible solution, my requirements are not concise, i need to add the filename for each document on the first page.

Comment: @Alberto, ok then. You could try adding it in the header or footer of the first page of each document before merging them into your new document

Comment: Please read [chapter 6 of "iText in Action - Second Edition"](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf) and look for the example that uses `PageStamp`. Read the official documentation, for instance [How to merge documents correctly?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-documents-correctly) and look for `PageStamp`. Also read [How to position text relative to page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-position-text-relative-page)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks a lot , i appreciate that you expend some time answering this question. Samples helped me a lot, now i have something working i just need now to refine it. One last question, you added the link to "How to merge documents correctly", because i'm not implementing merge correctly or because there is an example of how to add some text.

Comment: @NKosi thanks, but Bruno pointed me on the right direction.

Comment: @Alberto, great. glad you were able to figure it out. Happy coding!!!

Comment: @Alberto It is a coincidence that the question has that title ;-) I referred to it because of the `PageStamp` example. Sorry for the confusion. You were using the correct classes to merge PDFs.

Comment: Perfect!! @BrunoLowagie thanks again